# Python update list with dict values

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary, append

This question seems basic but I did not find a clean solution for it.

I want to add some values (dictionary) to one list, e.g.

```
data = { "item" : {}, "series": [ ] }
...
data['item'].update(dict(labels=myitems))   
data['series'].append( dict(data=myseriesData) )       
data['series'].append( dict(name=myname) )
```

This produces:

```
{'series': [{'data': [1, 2, 3]}, {'name': 'serie1'}], 'item': {'labels': ['jan', 'feb', 'march']}}
```

Although I don't what the curly-braces in the series list, my JSON needs to be in the following format:

```
{'series': ['data': [1, 2, 3], 'name': 'serie1'], 'item': {'labels': ['jan', 'feb', 'march']}}
```

I've tried different approaches like using *extend* *update* add a string or tuple but without success..

Any idea? what is the "trick"?

Comment: It's because you're appending a dictionary

Comment: You made matters worse. Try putting what you are asking for in a JSON validator like http://jsonlint.com/. Your expected output is invalid.

Comment: Your json sample is invalid; you are missing a few curly braces, and JSON uses double quotes. You cannot have key-value pairs in a list. Did you mean `{"series": [{"data": [1, 2, 3], "name": "serie1"}], "item": {"labels": ["jan", "feb", "march"]}}` instead? Note the double quotes.

Comment: the desired output is: {'series': ['data': [1, 2, 3], 'name': 'serie1'], 'item': {'labels': ['jan', 'feb', 'march']}}. I edit my initial json. thanks

Answer (score 3):

Append only a single `dict`.

```
data['series'].append(dict(data=myseriesData, name=myname))
```

Comment: This does not work, it produces the following output: This does not work, it produces the following output: {'series': [ {'data': [1, 2, 3], 'name': 'serie1' } ], 'item': {'labels': ['jan', 'feb', 'march']}} Note, the series [  { .. } ] curly-braces should not be present

Comment: @Algina: then specify what output you **expect**, otherwise we'll be here all day going back and forth as we zoom in on what you wanted.

Comment: Sorry Martijn, press enter too early! The thing is that inside the list [] i don't want the curly braces, it should be: only .. 'series' :['data': [123, 100, 123, 255], 'name': 'serie1']

Comment: @Algina: That's not a valid structure, in Python or JSON.

Comment: @Algina: that's not possible. Not in Python, not in JSON.